# facebook login using sdk v4.0 and getting users name and email

Tags: php, mysql, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

```
require_once( 'lib/Facebook/FacebookSession.php');
require_once( 'lib/Facebook/FacebookRequest.php' );
require_once( 'lib/Facebook/FacebookResponse.php' );
require_once( 'lib/Facebook/FacebookSDKException.php' );
require_once( 'lib/Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php' );
require_once( 'lib/Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php');
require_once( 'lib/Facebook/FacebookAuthorizationException.php' );
require_once( 'lib/Facebook/GraphObject.php' );
require_once( 'lib/Facebook/GraphUser.php' );
require_once( 'lib/Facebook/GraphSessionInfo.php' );
require_once( 'lib/Facebook/Entities/AccessToken.php');
require_once( 'lib/Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurl.php' );
require_once( 'lib/Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookHttpable.php');
require_once( 'lib/Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurlHttpClient.php');

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\GraphUser;
use Facebook\GraphSessionInfo;
use Facebook\FacebookHttpable;
use Facebook\FacebookCurlHttpClient;
use Facebook\FacebookCurl
session_start();

if(isset($_REQUEST['logout'])) {
    unset($_SESSION['fb_token']);
}

$app_id = 'xxx';
$app_secret = 'xxx';
$redirect_url='http://thankqteacher.com/test/index.php';
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($app_id,$app_secret);
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper($redirect_url);
$sess = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();

//check if facebook session exists
if(isset($_SESSION['fb_token'])) {
    $sess = new FacebookSession($_SESSION['fb_token']);
}
$logout = 'http://thankqteacher.com/test/index.php&logout=true';

if(isset($sess)) {
    //store the token in the php session
    $_SESSION['fb_token']=$sess->getToken();
    //create request object,execute and capture response
    $request = new FacebookRequest($sess,'GET','/me');
    // from response get graph object
    $response = $request->execute();
    $graph = $response->getGraphObject(GraphUser::classname());
    // use graph object methods to get user details
    $name = $graph->getName();
    $id = $graph->getId();
    $image = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$id.'/picture?width=300';
    $email = $graph->getProperty('email');
    echo "hi $name <br>";
    echo "your email is $email <br><Br>";
    echo "<img src='$image' /><br><br>";
    echo "<a href='".$logout."'><button>Logout</button></a>";
} else {
    //else echo login
     echo '<a href="'.$helper->getLoginUrl().'" >Login with       facebook</a>';
}
```

the above code is taking the permission from user to get the name and email and picture abut then after wards its appearing blank with code as the parameter to url which is encrypted text its not satisfying the if condition to display the email and name of user i have listed all the url paths as correctly in my app

Comment: Why still use v4 of the SDK? The current version is v5, and the documentation has lots of examples for that.